# Hardwareinventory - Copy Record with values in Access 2016 Web App

Tags: microsoft-office, vba, macros, microsoft-access, database

I want to make a WebApp in Access which help me inventory all our Hardware.

Below is a VERY wip ERM for the Database behind it. Every CPU-Object is its owm physical thing (if we have 2x i5-3450 there is 2 objects with same stats but differend ID).

In the WebApp it looks like this:

[image]

I need some function which copys the selected Record with all its values and adds it as a new record with a new ID. Best would be if I can reuse it easily for all the other tables too. So far I tried a Datamacro but those don't seem to be able to access the selected object.

I just need is a pointer in the right direction. Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I'm able to copy if I switch to DatasheetView. You can just select the line with all the values and use Str+C and STR+V

Comment: This is not an answer. If you figured it out, great! We love it when askers answer their own question - but please provide enough information about what you did or how it works so that future visitors can learn.

Comment: I edited so it's a bit more clear, but that's all there is to it